# React native Pagination with carousel

Tags: react-native, pagination, carousel

**Hey!**

Shortly, i want to use Pagination in my Expo app, cant figure out how to do it with the React native Carousel Pagination doc.
[Pagination Docs link](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/master/doc/PAGINATION.md)

Data Array:

```
 const data = [
{
  bars: [
    { x: "Sun", y: 50 },
    { x: "Mon", y: 100 },
    { x: "Tue", y: 150 },
    { x: "Wed", y: 200 },
    { x: "Thr", y: 250 },
    { x: "Fri", y: 300 },
  ],
},
{
  pie: [
    { x: "Men", y: 35 },
    { x: "Women", y: 40 },
    { x: "Children", y: 55 },
  ],
},
```

];

RenderItem(Sample from it, the other "IF" is similar to the one here:

```
const RenderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
if (item.bars) {
  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            textAlign: "center",
            fontWeight: "600",
            color: "black",
          }}
        >
          Weekly Income Graph:
        </Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <VictoryChart>
          <VictoryGroup>
            <VictoryBar
              data={item.bars}
              alignment="start"
              barRatio={0.2}
              style={{ data: { fill: "#c43a31" } }}
            />
          </VictoryGroup>
        </VictoryChart>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
```

Pagination component:

```
 <Pagination
      dotsLength={data.length}
      activeDotIndex={} // Cant figure out what to put here.
      dotStyle={{
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 8,
        color: "black",
      }}
      inactiveDotStyle={{
        color: "green",
      }}
      inactiveDotOpacity={0.4}
      inactiveDotScale={0.6}
    />
```

Carousel:

```
<Carousel
      layout={"tinder"}
      ref={carouselRef}
      data={data} 
      renderItem={RenderItem}
      sliderWidth={width}
      itemWidth={width - 10}
      swipeThreshold={100}
      layoutCardOffset={-12}
      inactiveSlideOpacity={0.4}
      containerCustomStyle={{
        overflow: "visible",
        marginVertical: 5,
      }}
      contentContainerCustomStyle={{
        paddingTop: 0,
      }}
    />
```

**Im truly sorry for the long code and post.**
**I simply cant figure out how to adapt the docs i attached above with my code.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to implement `onSnapToItem` on Carousel component.

You should also create a state that hold active slide index. When you swipe left/right each time onSnapToItem get fired and within the function you gave to onSnapToItem, you should set the current slide index so that sliding effect can occur.

```
const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);

<Carousel>
    ...
       onSnapToItem={(index) => setActiveSlide(index) }
    ...
    </Carousel>
```

Here is the demo [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@nicefella82/react-native-snap-carousel)